# How to define database context

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/working-with-sql) on how to use .NET Core with SQLite3 and VSCode, but it is not made very clear what is meant by `MvcMovieContext`.

I understand that this is a db context from which calls to the database can be made, but how do I define this?

In my startup.cs I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add the whole configuration object here
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=LogonChecker.db"));
}
```

But of course I get

> 'The type or namespace name 'DBContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So my question is - what am I supposed to do with this? Just declare an empty `DBContext` class? All I want to do is create an extremely simple app which stores data in a sqlite database. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What research into Entity Framework have you done?

Comment: [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) (note the letter casing) is the base class for working with Entity Framework database mapping. The type argument in your config needs to be something defined in your project somewhere. If you want to use Sqlite, you're going to need to add the provider first. Probably want to start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are following assumes prior knowledge of Entity Framework--where the DbContext class comes from. I would follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) to get up and running with EF on .NET core.